# How can I style QTableView's entire row border when it is selected?

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to do what I can only describe as "selection-border-radius" would intuitively do for QTableView rows.

Comment: An image would make this question more clear...

Comment: there is not any CSS variable for the selection border-radius. but you can delegate your items and customize the selection style.

Comment: @hyde it's like the telegram web contact selection. Sorry, I can't find any images for this specific thing :(

Comment: @SajadBlog how can I go about doing that?

Comment: You could add an image of how it looks like now, with a screenshot and then explain, or even draw on top of  a copy of the screenshot, how you want it different.